# No 10k-Tools to Watch Users?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, 10k-tools

I just cleared the 10k mark on SO (feels good) and was happy to see the new "Tools" link. While the content is pretty interesting, I'm curious why no user-specific data is being served up? For example, most-active, most-answering, most-asking, most-upvoted, most-downvoted, etc.

Is this type of data available? If so, is there a reason why it's not available in part or in full to the 10k+ users?

Comment: but who watches the watchers???

Comment: Rob Allen: Those who own the DVD

Comment: Mazel Tov on your 10k!

Comment: Joining the 10k club doesn't mean you to be part of a Stackoverflow gestapo.

Comment: @Rex - That's right!  It's a *Cabal*!  Get that straight right now, and the rest is smooth sailing.

Answer (score 16):

This is philosophically the wrong thing to watch, and it would send the wrong message if implemented.

You don't watch *users*.

You watch *actions*.

The difference is hugely important.

Comment: Exactly. I was scrolling down to write the same thing.

Comment: I disagree, Jeff. "Users" here means nothing more than a global set of actions tied to an integer-value. Fine, don't show us *users*. Can we see globally-related actions with high-upvote velocity central to a single integer-value?

Comment: Jonathan: You can already see other actions central to the integer value relevant to some action by going to the user profile of the user.

Comment: Mehrdad - how do I find the common integer-value associated with most up-votes for the day?

Answer (score 1):

I've said repeatedly that once you hit 10k, it's sort of a buzz-kill when you actually look at the tools available.

The only real "power" that 10k users have is that they can see the Spam/Offensive flags on questions (they don't get to see the moderator attention flags), as well as being able to vote to delete closed items (after 24 hours of being closed), and vote to undelete items. The voting process for these is 3 votes to delete, 3 votes to undelete.

Comment: Yeah; kinda Wizard-of-ozzy...Was expecting "sha-baaaang!"

Comment: Once I hit 10k I'm just going to sit and make my own (Greasemonkey) tools.

Comment: @Chacha - I've already started thinking about that ;) A whole new set of data to query.

Comment: When you get a chance, check out my filters script. Found it very useful to filter the homepage/questions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11096/filter-questions-greasemonkey-script

Comment: Actually the best power is being able to see deleted post #1.  (well, and the other deleted posts, I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

If the engine were making this information available, I'm not sure why it would be relevant to only 10k+ users. I haven't seen what tools do become available at that point, but my understanding is it is tools that will help the users' moderate the site more efficiently and outside of most-downvoted (perhaps), I'm not sure the ones you called out would be useful for that task. Certainly I understand being interested in this information, but I'm not sure why it would be something that you should "earn" in the system; either it's there or it isn't.

Comment: Completely agree. This isn't more relevant to 10k users.

Comment: The tools don't really help you moderate anything. Actually, 10k users don't have moderator abilities from what I see. We can only *see* things that others don't see, like deleted posts/answers. We do have some slight advantages, like being able to vote on an item that is a couple days old, but nothing spectacular. The tools are just a treat, not a necessity.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan - I would add a comment (but still can't)...

"Don't rub in your SO greatness to some of us less fortunate under 10K'ers..."  I kid, I kid...

It would be interesting to see the breakdown in functionality that for 10K'ers and Moderators to see what each can and can't do...

Comment: From what I can tell, the two are radically different. 10k'ers can see deleted items, etc., but I don't see that I have any real influence over questions/posts. In fact, I don't :) I just get in on some slightly lesser-known statistics.

Comment: Jonathan, 10k users can vote to delete closed posts (takes 3 votes to delete) and vote to undelete as well (same 3 votes apply).

Comment: Well, yeah...but, they're already closed :) Doesn't really seem to be all that big of a deal.

Comment: I think deleting is rather important to keeping the clutter down long-term. Atwood appears to do periodic sweeps, but eventually it's gonna get out of hand. I encourage you to vote to delete posts that are sitting closed without any reason to exist (excluding duplicates that might help point searchers in the right direction, for instance).